# onClick insert a text/time in field javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In brief I want to have only 1 button and if I clicked that button it inserts a time in the text field that I just selected. (I have 20 fields) I don't want to add a button to each field.

I'm using something like this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(
    function() {

        $('#TIME').click(function() {
            var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: false});
            $('#TIME').val(time);
        });

    }
);
</script>


<div class="timebuttons">

</div>
```

Comment: tip. dont use () as blocks {} when not necessary. format your code properly

Comment: use class instead of id it may help you because you can give as many class as you like but you cant give same id for different element

Comment: I don't understand, where is the button with `TIME` id? Where do you want to put the text after click? Do you want to change the text of the button clicked or add a new text to `timebuttons` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution (along with a validaion ) https://jsfiddle.net/4zyy9tr7/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $focused = "";

  $('.setTime').focus(function(){
      $focused = $(this);
  });

  //Set time in last selected input field when the button is clicked    
  $('#btnSetTime').click(function() {
      var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: false});
      if($focused != "")
        $focused.val(time);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="setTime" value="" />
<input type="text" class="setTime" value="" />
<input type="text" class="setTime" value="" />
<input type="text" class="setTime" value="" />
<button id="btnSetTime">Set Time</button>
```

Validation:
If you haven't selected a `input textbox` & you clicked **Set Time** `button`, you won't see any error.

I've used `jQuery` `focus` method.

**Updated code**

```
 $('#btnSetTime').click(function() {
  var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: false});
  if($focused != "")
    $focused.val(time);

  return false;
 });
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, however is there any way to stop the bottom from submitting the form everytime is click?

Comment: Use `return false;` inside the click event.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: for a textfield everytime i click it resets it, is there a way to just insert time and not empy and insert.